# Capturing html source as text and then searching with xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Using Selenium in Python.

I have a scraping tool that opens a site, grabs text elements using XPath, cleans those elements, and closes the page. The tool is getting too bulky to clean the elements while the driver is still connected. So what I want to do is instead open the page, grab the entire HTML source, close the page, and then grab what I want out of the page using xpaths. But since the page is now just text, I'm unable to use the XPath methods in selenium. Any recommendations?

Comment: You should consider using Beautifulsoup as a web scraping tool. It should work fine in your situation- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Try with Beautifulsoup and if you get stuck put the code here and we will help